# Tuning query with multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning

i have this query .. 
214 Execution/min , 44.42 Avg CPU(ms) 
is there a way to make it much faster

```
SELECT        P.Id id0,
              P.ProgramId ProgramId1,
              P.ProgramName ProgramName2,
              P.ProgramLevel ProgramLevel3,
              P.Department Department4,
              P.Track Track5,
              P.AcademicYear AcademicYear6,
              P.StartTerm StartTerm7,
              P.Delivery Delivery8,
              P.Fee Fee9,
              P.City City10,
              P.STATE State11,
              P.StartDate StartDate12,
              P.Deadline Deadline13,
              P.DeadlineDisplay DeadlineDisplay14,
              P.ProgramType ProgramType15,
              O.Id as OrganizationId16,
              O.NAME OrganizationName17,
              P.ApplicationType ApplicationType18,
              P.Concentration Concentration19,
              P.ZipCode ZipCode20,
              P.Campus Campus21,
              P.WADisplayName WADisplayName22,
              P.UpdatedDate updateDate23,
              AF.Id InstanceId24,
              RD.Id stateId33
INTO #TempGetFullProgramSelectionInfo            
FROM    unicas_config..applicationForm AF  
  INNER JOIN UNICAS_CONFIG.. AcademicInstitution AI
           ON AF.casid=AI.casid 
  INNER JOIN UNICAS_CONFIG..Organization O 
           ON O.academicInstitutionid=AI.id   
  INNER JOIN UNICAS_CONFIG..AssociationOrg asOrg
           ON asOrg.FormId=AF.id
  INNER JOIN  UNICAS_CONFIG..Program P
           ON P.AssociationOrgId=asOrg.Id and asOrg.OrganizationId=O.id AND AF.Id = 6286
  INNER JOIN  unicas_config..ReferenceData RD 
                 ON P.STATE = RD.ValueId AND RD.ValueAbbr ='US'
  INNER JOIN  unicas_config..ReferenceDataSet RS  
           ON RD.ReferenceSetId = RS.SetId AND RS.NAME = 'LK_States'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now this  if i split  to 2 queries

```
select RD.ValueId, RD.id into #temp1
from   unicas_config..ReferenceData RD
INNER JOIN  unicas_config..ReferenceDataSet RS   ON RD.ReferenceSetId= RS.SetId AND RS.NAME= 'LK_States'
where RD.ValueAbbr='US';


SELECT        P.Id id0,
              P.ProgramId ProgramId1,
              P.ProgramName ProgramName2,
              P.ProgramLevel ProgramLevel3,
              P.Department Department4,
              P.Track Track5,
              P.AcademicYear AcademicYear6,
              P.StartTerm StartTerm7,
              P.Delivery Delivery8,
              P.Fee Fee9,
              P.City City10,
              P.STATE State11,
              P.StartDate StartDate12,
              P.Deadline Deadline13,
              P.DeadlineDisplay DeadlineDisplay14,
              P.ProgramType ProgramType15,
              O.Id as OrganizationId16,
              O.NAME OrganizationName17,
              P.ApplicationType ApplicationType18,
              P.Concentration Concentration19,
              P.ZipCode ZipCode20,
              P.Campus Campus21,
              P.WADisplayName WADisplayName22,
              P.UpdatedDate updateDate23,
              AF.Id InstanceId24,
              RD.Id stateId33
INTO #TempGetFullProgramSelectionInfo            
FROM    unicas_config..applicationForm AF  
  INNER JOIN UNICAS_CONFIG.. AcademicInstitution AI
           ON AF.casid=AI.casid 
  INNER JOIN UNICAS_CONFIG..Organization O 
           ON O.academicInstitutionid=AI.id   
  INNER JOIN UNICAS_CONFIG..AssociationOrg asOrg
           ON asOrg.FormId=AF.id
  INNER JOIN  UNICAS_CONFIG..Program P
           ON P.AssociationOrgId=asOrg.Id and asOrg.OrganizationId=O.id AND AF.Id = 6286
  INNER JOIN    #temp1 RD ON P.STATE= RD.ValueId;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

using the query recommended by Frisbee

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Using Hash join**

[image]

[image]

Comment: How much time does the query needs to run now? And why is it executed 200 times per minute? Can you explain the need to save the results into a temp table so often?

Comment: this query is in a SP and the temp table is used in the next query. this production has around  20 K request per min.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try
You have some (potentially) misplaced join conditions

```
SELECT        P.Id id0,
              P.ProgramId ProgramId1,
              P.ProgramName ProgramName2,
              P.ProgramLevel ProgramLevel3,
              P.Department Department4,
              P.Track Track5,
              P.AcademicYear AcademicYear6,
              P.StartTerm StartTerm7,
              P.Delivery Delivery8,
              P.Fee Fee9,
              P.City City10,
              P.STATE State11,
              P.StartDate StartDate12,
              P.Deadline Deadline13,
              P.DeadlineDisplay DeadlineDisplay14,
              P.ProgramType ProgramType15,
              O.Id as OrganizationId16,
              O.NAME OrganizationName17,
              P.ApplicationType ApplicationType18,
              P.Concentration Concentration19,
              P.ZipCode ZipCode20,
              P.Campus Campus21,
              P.WADisplayName WADisplayName22,
              P.UpdatedDate updateDate23,
              AF.Id InstanceId24,
              RD.Id stateId33
INTO #TempGetFullProgramSelectionInfo            
FROM       UNICAS_CONFIG..Organization O                 
INNER JOIN UNICAS_CONFIG..AcademicInstitution AI
            ON AI.id = O.academicInstitutionid        
INNER JOIN unicas_config..applicationForm AF
            ON AF.casid = AI.casid  
           AND AF.Id = 6286   
INNER JOIN UNICAS_CONFIG..AssociationOrg asOrg
            ON asOrg.FormId         = AF.id
           and asOrg.OrganizationId = O.id
INNER JOIN UNICAS_CONFIG..Program P
            ON P.AssociationOrgId = asOrg.Id 
INNER JOIN unicas_config..ReferenceData RD 
            ON RD.ValueId = P.STATE  
           AND RD.ValueAbbr ='US'
INNER JOIN unicas_config..ReferenceDataSet RS  
            ON RS.SetId = RD.ReferenceSetId   
           AND RS.NAME = 'LK_States'
```

If #temp has indexes then sort on the one that makes the most sense

If that does not improve response then just force a hash join on all
Still use the select in my answer - add the HASH to the query above

```
INNER HASH JOIN
```

Comment: i tried your query but there is not much improvement. also i know it is not recommended to use INNER Hash Join in Production.
Also i didn't get what you mean by"Still use the select in my answer"

Comment: Not much improvement - is that a bad thing?.   Not recommended to use INNER Hash Join in Production?  Where did you hear that?   Why don't you give it a try for grins?

Comment: added the execution plan to .. this query is most consuming CPU and IO on production. based on the number i am getting higher duration and more writes and same cpu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800124/advantages-in-specifying-hash-join-over-just-doing-a-join .. but i will give it a try and let you know . thanks

Comment: AF.Id = 6286 is not hard coded in the query , it is a parameter  passed to the SP .. i just used this number for testing

Comment: So based on one SE answer you conclude never use in production?  That answer does not even say never.  Is there any warning from Microsoft?  Really Microsoft put in a feature too fragile to actually use in production without warning.  So you are not even going to give it a try.  Oh no it may work today but in 30 days be totally broken?   You would  hack in a second table to get a hash join but not just specify hash join?

Comment: So AF.ID is not hard coded.  Does not change my answer.  You did say you got some improvement?

Comment: sorry i mean to add the comment the   AF.Id = 6286 is not hard coded in the query to my question not to you .. i know it i will not change your answer :-)

Comment: Also i said i will test using hash  join and well let you know. i didn't say i will not use it.

Comment: i used Hash join and getting better results .. but why you recommend to use 1 query instead of 2 .. i changed the join condition as you mentioned using 2 queries and got the best results

Comment: If two was better then maybe.  I would tweak one before I split it up.  Try hash on only the more static tables.   A second table is potentially less scalable.  If  RS.SetId is singular you could read that into variable and eliminate a join with a lot less overhead than another #temp.  I see a lot of things I would try before a second table here.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the following index (assuming it doesn't already exist)

```
CREATE INDEX ix_Organization_academicInstitutionid
    ON Organization(academicInstitutionid, Id) INCLUDE (Name)
```

Comment: there is a Non Clustered Index on academicInstitutionid  and a Clustred Index on ID ..

Comment: Specifically is there an include (name) on the index on academicInstitutionid?

Comment: yes name is included also .. does it matter if it is 1 index or 2 indexes

Comment: You mean that you have the clustered index on id and the second one on academicInstitutionId include(name)? I'd go ahead and create the composite index.  If you look at your plans most of them are doing clustered index seeks.  The idea is to try to make it an index seek instead.

Answer (score 0):

Before making any change to script, just do an index rebuid on all the involved tables and see if there is any significant increase. (at least, do a table level statistics rebuild with full scan)

[Program] seems like a big table, make ensure **P.AssociationOrgId** is indexed.

Comment: i rebuild statistics everyday and all indexes were rebuild